# Communicate two form based springboot application using rest

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have two Springboot application. One is for addition and second for subtraction. I have created only one form in html for both addition and subtraction.

What I want is when I click on Subtraction, it should call subtraction logic and do subtraction of two values coming from html using REST.

Comment: Do you really have two separate back end applications? Or one application with two different API endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

> I have two springboot application

Have you considered using *RestTemplate* for making rest call/inter-communication?

Let me know:)I will edit for the same.

**Edited:**

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpEntity<ObjectContainingBothP> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<ObjectContainingBothParams>(ObjectContainingBothParams);
final String urlofanothermethodinanotherspringboot=//whole url;
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(urlofanothermethodinanotherspringboot);
ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(), HttpMethod.POST,
                httpEntity, response.class//reponse that you want back);
Response response = exchange.getBody();
```

Though you can use WebClient instead of RestTemplate,it completely depends on the requirement:

> RestTemplate:-synchronous and blocking,you cant proceed further untill reponse comes back.
>   WebClient:-you dont need to wait.

considering your situation,i think Rest Template is :).

Comment: Yes, I have used rest for inter-communication and one more thing, I have used thymeleaf forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) class.

```
String exampleYourUrl = "http://localhost:8080/calculate/subtract";

UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(exampleYourUrl)
            .queryParam("param1", "12")
            .queryParam("param2", "3");
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
Integer response = restTemplate.getForObject(uriBuilder.toUriString(), Integer.class);
```

Comment: Assuming the OP uses Spring 5+, the new `WebClient` is the better choice. `RestTemplate` will become deprecated.

Comment: It even says so in the link you provided: "The RestTemplate will be deprecated in a future version and will not have major new features added going forward."